# Sonarcloud not finding obvious C problems

Tags: sonarqube, sonarcloud

I made a very simple C file just to test the output of sonarcloud when using C code. My entire code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

 int i;

 for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    void* unreleasedMemory = malloc(1024);
    printf("Address: %p\n", unreleasedMemory);
 }

 printf("Uninitialized i is: %d", i);
 return 0;

}
```

When I start a new project on sonarcloud and issue both build-wrapper and sonar-scanner commands like this:

```
build-wrapper-macosx-x86 --out-dir bw-output cmake .
```

After that:

```
sonar-scanner \
-Dsonar.projectKey=ctest \
-Dsonar.organization=<orgname> \
-Dsonar.sources=. \
-Dsonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw-output \
-Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io \
-Dsonar.login=<tokenvalue>
```

Output of both parameters looks fine. Unfortunately, it doesn't detect these fairly obvious errors:

[image]

What am I doing wrong so sonarcloud will pick them up?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain how you trigger the analysis? More precisely, how you are using build wrapper and configuring it.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam: edited.

Comment: Can you also give a link to the scanner logs (on a Gist for instance) to check if anything wrong is detected during analysis? We tried to reproduce your case, and we have issues reported on it: https://sonarcloud.io/project/issues?id=godin-test&open=AWO9BQoQ4fWm9CZEQwBS&resolved=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Building+on+Mac+OS+X :

> Add execution of Build Wrapper as a prefix to the usual **build command that you use to build your project** (the example below uses xcodebuild, but any build tool that performs a **full build** can be used)

In other words: **all files that should be analyzed must be compiled during execution of `build-wrapper`**. This is needed because `build-wrapper` watches compiler invocations to gather information about which files are compiled in your project and with which options, then this information is used for analysis during execution of `sonar-scanner`.

I seriously doubt that your execution of `cmake .` performs compilation of `main.c` - it just generates make-files, and thus that's why `main.c` is actually not analyzed properly.

Execution of

```
cmake .
build-wrapper-macosx-x86 --out-dir bw-output make clean all
```

followed by execution of `sonar-scanner` with `-Dsonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw-output` produces desired result:

[image: example]